# Probabilistic SVM, how does it actually work?

Tags: python, svm, probability

After some time I think I've finally implemented what's been called a probabilistic SVM. The code I've been using is this:

```
 numpy as np
import random
from sklearn.svm import SVC
import math
from scipy.optimize import minimize
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from sklearn import decomposition
from sklearn import svm
from sklearn.model_selection import GridSearchCV
from sklearn.model_selection import train_test_split
import warnings
warnings.filterwarnings("ignore")

def training_banana(name):
    inputs = []
    file = open(name, "r")
    for line in file:
        vector = line.split()
        coordinate = []
        for i in range(len(vector)):
            coordinate.append(float(vector[i]))
        inputs.append(coordinate)
    file.close()

    return np.array(inputs)


def define_inputs(name, name_targets):
    inputs = training_banana(name)
    targets_array = training_banana(name_targets)
    N = targets_array.shape[0]
    targets = np.zeros(N)
    for i in range(N):
        targets[i] = targets_array[i][0]
    return inputs, targets, N

#training set
inputs_train, targets_train, N = define_inputs('banana_train.txt', 'banana_train_label.txt')
permute = list(range(N))
random.shuffle(permute)
inputs_train = inputs_train[permute, :]
targets_train = targets_train[permute]

#test set
inputs_test, targets_test, N = define_inputs('banana_test.txt', 'banana_test_label.txt')
permute = list(range(N))
random.shuffle(permute)
inputs_test = inputs_test[permute, :]
targets_test = targets_test[permute]


def plotting():
    ax = plt.gca()
    param_C = [0.01, 0.1, 1, 10, 100]
    param_grid = {'C': param_C, 'kernel': ['poly','rbf', 'linear'], 'gamma': [0.1, 0.01, 0.001, 0.0001]}
    clf = GridSearchCV(SVC(class_weight='balanced'), param_grid)
    clf.fit(inputs_train, targets_train)
    index = clf.best_estimator_.n_support_
    print(clf.best_params_['kernel'])
    clf = SVC(C=clf.best_params_['C'], cache_size=200, class_weight=None, coef0=0.0,
        decision_function_shape='ovr', degree=5, gamma=clf.best_params_['gamma'], kernel=clf.best_params_['kernel'],
        max_iter=-1, probability=True, random_state=None, shrinking=True,
        tol=0.001, verbose=False)
    clf.fit(inputs_train, targets_train)
    support_vectors = []
    for i in range(len(index)):
        support_vectors.append(inputs_train[i])
    support_vectors = np.array(support_vectors)
    xx = np.linspace(-4, 4, 1000)
    yy = np.linspace(-4, 4, 1000).T
    xx, yy = np.meshgrid(xx, yy)
    Xfull = np.c_[xx.ravel(), yy.ravel()]
    probabilities = clf.predict_proba(inputs_test)
    predicting_classes_pos_targets = []
    predicting_classes_pos_inputs = []
    predicting_classes_neg_targets = []
    predicting_classes_neg_inputs = []
    prob_mesh = clf.predict_proba(Xfull)
    #print(Xfull)
    #for i in range(inputs_test.shape[0]):
    b = 0
    q = 0
    print(clf.predict([inputs_test[0]])[0])
    for i in range(100):
        if clf.predict([inputs_test[i]]) >= 0:
            predicting_classes_pos_targets.append(1)
            predicting_classes_pos_inputs.append(inputs_test[i]) #Problmet ligger här
            b = b+1
        else:
            predicting_classes_neg_targets.append(-1)
            predicting_classes_neg_inputs.append(inputs_test[i])
            q = q+1
    predicting_classes_pos_inputs = np.array(predicting_classes_pos_inputs)
    predicting_classes_neg_inputs = np.array(predicting_classes_neg_inputs)
    #print(predicting_classes_pos_inputs.shape)
    #print(prob)
    #print(predicting_classes_pos_inputs)
    #print(np.min(inputs_test[:,0]))
    #print(np.max(inputs_test[:,0]))
    #print(np.min(inputs_test[:, 1]))
    #print(np.max(inputs_test[:, 1]))
    #plt.scatter(predicting_classes_pos_inputs[:, 0], predicting_classes_pos_inputs[:, 1], c="b", s=30, cmap=plt.cm.Paired)
    plt.subplot(1, 2, 1)
    plt.imshow(prob_mesh[:, 1].reshape((1000, 1000)),
               extent=(-4, 4, -4, 4), origin='lower')
    plt.scatter(predicting_classes_pos_inputs[:, 0], predicting_classes_pos_inputs[:, 1], marker='o', c='w',
                edgecolor='k')
    plt.subplot(1,2,2)
    plt.imshow(prob_mesh[:, 0].reshape((1000, 1000)),
               extent=(-4, 4, -4, 4), origin='lower')
    plt.scatter(predicting_classes_neg_inputs[:, 0], predicting_classes_neg_inputs[:, 1], marker='o', c='w',
                edgecolor='k')

    #plt.xticks(())
    #plt.yticks(())
    #plt.colorbar(imshow_handle, cax=ax, orientation='horizontal')
    #plt.colorbar(imshow_handle, cax=ax, orientation='horizontal')
    plt.show()
```

[image]

I'm trying to read up on theory how this works, but it looks like there are several different methods of how you can make this implementation. I'm therefore curious, how does the probabilistic SVM really work and is there any good literature that I can follow, because I need some sort of theory for the project I'm currently writing (comparing SVM and RVM). Thanks in advance!

Comment: Yet another question I have, is it possible to use the probabilistic SVM for regression as well?

Comment: Does SVC use the log loss function to calculate parameters ?